# PayPal Adaptive Payments with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I'm looking for a lightweight gem that will allow me to do Adaptive Payments with PayPal through my Rails 3 application.

I've looked at https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment and https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive.

Neither of them have worked for me so far (tested on Heroku).  Does anyone know of any up-to-date solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use active_paypal_adaptive_payment and it works reasonably well. I've also sent some pull requests to it which make it work better. :-P

Answer (score 0):

On rails 3 we use

```
gem 'paypal_adaptive', '0.1.0'
```

That has worked for us in production using Rails 3.0.7